# How to access MethodInvocation that is inside a VariableDeclarationStatement

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt, method-invocation

I am checking for the invocation of a method using JDT and performing a check on its argument. I am using an AST Visitor class which visits MethodInvocation nodes and performs this operation. I use the below method in the Visitor class.

```
    public boolean visit(MethodInvocation node) {

        if (node.getName().toString().equals("createQuery")) {

            String argument= node.arguments().get(0).toString();

            // process the argument here

        }

        return true;
    }
```

But the invocation which are part of a Variable Declaration are not being visted.

eg: If i am looking for the invocation of a method 'createQuery', the below invocation would be visited.

```
    session.createQuery("some query here");
```

Bu this one is not visited.

```
    Query query = session.createQuery("another query here");
```

How can i visit such statements and fetch the arguments in a proper way?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.. Have to visit the VariableDeclarationStatement node in the AST and return a true.

```
public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationStatement node) {

    return true;
}
```

This enables the visit to the childs of the VariableDeclarationStatement in the AST. The particular type of Method invocation comes as a child of the VariableDeclarationStatement node, thus they are also visited.